# finding bad usage of doygen own tags

Tags: c++, doxygen

- I'm using doxygen and have defined my own tags in the doxyfile.
  Now I want to parse for correct usage of the tags e.g. no blank after mytag.

```
    @mytag{correct}
    @mytag {incorrect}
```

and other patterns. I could use a text parser to go through the header files etc. but is there a more advanced, convenient way?

Good example is:

```
\reqtest{...}
```

And a common mistake is

```
\ reqtest{...}
```

Or

```
\reqtest{...}\n
```

Or

```
\reqtest{...}@n
```

Or a combination of the above

- Same question also for non doxygen code comments.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Why not run doxygen and let doxygen decide? Can you give an example where it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Have you tried posting to the Doxygen forum(s) or discussion boards?

Comment: Im using the latest version of doxygen, , I have special formatting rules for my custom tags for example if there is a link in it certain text is not allowed; I doubt that doxygen supports adding such rules

Comment: \reqtest{...}

And a common mistake is
\ reqtest{...}

Or

\reqtest{...}\n

Or

patterns im using are for example 
\reqtest{...}@n

Or a combination

Comment: "Im using the latest version of doxygen" this is a moving target and only contains the information that you might be using the current doxygen version (1.9.6) or the current doxygen master version, so specify, in the question the result of `doxygen -v`

Comment: The given examples all look like valid commands just a bit uncommon, but one never knows what a user wants to write.

Comment: @albert version 1.9.6; 
 yes, all is valid doxygen, there are some machine checks afterwards that dont detect if there is a blank in between for example, and these are common faults, all faults I cannot prevent of course

Comment: I vaguely remember that there are some checks in Clang (but I never used them). Only possibility I see is you write your own `linter` or adjust the configuration of an existing `linter` or spell checker (like codespell, https://github.com/codespell-project/codespell.git and define here your own set of "incorrect" words, I don't know how it will handle `\`,  `@` and other special characters though) For some more inspiration see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis.

Comment: Regarding clang maybe see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html (option `-Wdocumentation`) though I have no idea what it will and won't flag.

Comment: thanks for the inspiration, having a look at clang looks like it does what doxygen already does, I will check what codespell can do for me ...

Comment: I had some problems with tool usage of codespell, how can I select what file types to scan and how can i use regexp patterns for word recognition?